# Weak and strong convergence on $W^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Can someone help me to understand why if $$u_n(x)\rightarrow 0,\, \text{a.e in}\, \mathbb{R}^N$$

then $$u_n\rightharpoonup 0,\, \text{in}\, W^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^N)$$

Thank you

Edit : $\|u_n\|_{1,N}$ is bounded

Comment: I think you mean to assume that $\|u_{n}\|_{W^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^{N})}$ is bounded.

Comment: yes I have this, is this work on any Sobolev space ?

Comment: Have you tried to mimic the proof for the $L^p$ case for the $W^{1,N}$ case?